# How do I query for geometry inside the Arctic Circle?

Tags: postgis-1.5

I have a large PostGIS database of lat/lon points.  How can I query for any points that lie above the Arctic Circle?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Are you restricted to ver 1.5? Newer versions bring speed and functional improvements. Also, you should specify what spatial reference system you have. Please use the "edit" button just above this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't simply if the Latitude is greater thank 66° 33′ 44 ( 66.5622°) North?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that:

- your points are in EPSG:4326
- all your points are in one table
- table name is 'my_table' and geometry collumn is 'geom'

The query could be:

```
select * from my_table where st_y(geom) > 66.5622;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast solutions usually involve [`ST_DWithin()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find points within some distance.

A *first* attempt tries to find those within 23.4378° of the pole:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ST_DWithin (ST_Point (0.0, 90.0), geom, 23.4378)
```

because `ST_DWithin()` uses the distance units of the SRS of the `geom` and (with Jendrusk's assumptions) they are degrees. However, **it won't work like that**. Can you see why?

A *second* attempt would use the "geography" version of the function:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE ST_DWithin (
    ST_Point (0.0, 90.0)::geography, 
    geom::geography, 
    23.4378)
```

But **that won't work either**. That angular distance now needs to be in meters.

A *third* approach adds the use of [`ST_Distance()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) to get the required distance:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE ST_DWithin (
    ST_Point (0.0, 90.0)::geography, 
    geom::geography, 
    ST_Distance (
        ST_Point (0.0, 90.0)::geography, 
        ST_Point (0.0, 66.5622)::geography
        )
    )
```

Whether that works out to be faster than Jendrusk's simple solution -- or even works at all (i didn't test it) -- i don't know!